# Put output of command prompt to clipboard

Tags: windows, cmd, command, prompt

[image: http://i.imgur.com/jrqDJ6s.png]

I would like the output of Privkey to be copied to the clipboard. I have found many different commands online, however they copy the file information instead of the output itself. I would just like the output of privkey. If thats not possible to do, even the entire log of the command prompt script saved would still be fine. Basically I just need a way to make it so its possible to copy text from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should provide just the Privkey data itself:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('vanitygen 1A ^| findstr Privkey ') do echo %%a|clip
```

Answer (score 5):

You can redirect the output of every command with `| clip` to clipboard. For example `dir | clip` copies a list of the files in the current directory to clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect full output to clipboard with `clip`.

In your example:

```
vanitygen 1A | clip
```

Now you can output only line you're interested to using `findstr`:

```
vanitygen 1A | findstr Privkey | clip
```

In short with | you send output of one command as input of the next one in the chain. `findstr` will then display only lines that contain given text (`Privkey`, in this example). Its output will be then sent to clipboard (`clip` sends its input to clipboard).

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly! Would it also be possible to remove the "Privkey: " from it, so it only displays the code?